# How to create dependencies between merged patch and before merged patch in gerrit?

Tags: linux, git, dependencies, patch, gerrit

I have two patches on `gerrit` and I would like to make the unmerged depened on the merged patch.

Both are uploaded to gerrit yet.

- How can I do it? Is it possible at all?
- can I do it through gerrit? not through [git](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Git/Workflow#Create_a_dependency) and cherry pick.

Let's say https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/34106/ is the unmerged file

The merged file https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/25756/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependencies in Gerrit are just a representation of the Git tree graph.  So to make change B depend on change A, B must have A as its parent.

In your case, you have two changes in two different repositories.  Cross-repository dependencies are not currently supported in Gerrit.  It is a [commonly-requested feature](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=377) however, and was just discussed at the Gerrit user conference last weekend.  Hopefully support for Cross-repository dependencies will be added in a future version of Gerrit.

Comment: Sorry - like I said above, what you want to do isn't currently possible in Gerrit.  This is something the devs are thinking about and working on.  Lots of users want to do this but can't currently.

Comment: I meant in git... so If someone look for this question he will see a solution.

Comment: The only way to support cross-repo dependencies in git is to use submodules.  There is a lot of documentation at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 3):

Using git commands taken from [here](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Git/Workflow#Create_a_dependency):

```
git fetch --all # Make sure we have latest info from the repository
git review -d 1234 # Gerrit change number of the change you want as dependency ("parent")

git checkout -b bug/1234 # Creates a new branch, with the current branch (the dependency) as parent
# Edit files: make your changes
git add someFile.php some/other/file.js 
git commit # Commit your patch

git log -n5 --decorate --pretty=oneline # Verify that the last 5 entries of the log now start with:
# * (HEAD, bug/1234) your change
# * (review/john/700) the dependency
# * (gerrit/master)

git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/master # Use this instead of `git review`

git branch # Take note of the review/* branch that was created for this, it has an "*" in front of it
git checkout bug/1234 # Check out the local topic branch of your change
git rebase review/john/7000 # The branch name of the gerrit change we checked out earlier

# Resolve conflicts if needed,
# - use "git status" to see the files that need resolution
# - after fixing it in your editor, "git add filename" for each of the fixed files 

git commit --amend -c HEAD # Re-commit your patch replacing the one with the wrong parent

git log -n5 --decorate --pretty=oneline # Verify that the last 5 entries of the log now start with:
# * (HEAD, bug/1234) your change
# * (review/john/700) the dependency
# * (gerrit/master)

git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/master # Use this instead of `git review`
```